# Server side event (SSE) in Flask pushes constantly instead of on request

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I have a Python Flask application that is supposed to push a server side event (SSE) to my webpage when specific events are triggered (e.g. via an interval timer, when the user pushes a specific button on the page etc.).

However, I do not get Flask to push a message only when I request the app to do so. Instead, after starting the app, it constantly keeps pushing a message to the server every few seconds which is not what I want.

My minimal example for this behaviour looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template, Response

from random import randint

app = Flask(__name__)

# function to push data to the server
def pushData():

    # randint is just to make every message not look the same
    number = randint(0,9)

    print('I push data to the server: {0}'.format(number))
    yield 'data: %s\n\n' % 'I am data that has been pushed to the server: {0}'.format(number)

# provide SSE stream to the web browser
@app.route('/listenForPushes')
def stream():

    return Response(pushData(), mimetype="text/event-stream")

# render a simple HTML page to the browser
@app.route('/html')
def html():
    return render_template('webpage.html')

# run this when the app starts. this should execute exactly one push at app start.
@app.before_first_request
def _run_on_start():
    pushData()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, threaded=True, use_reloader=False, port=3000)
```

The HTML page with the event listener for SSE called `webpage.html` (put in the folder `templates` so that Flask can find it without any further configuration) looks like this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
    <body>This is a test page, please check the console output.

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var source = new EventSource('/listenForPushes');
        source.onmessage = function(event) {
            console.log(event.data);
        }

    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

When I now start the application, I get constantly messages pushed to the page every 2-3 seconds so that the output in the Python console and the browser's console look like this (right click the image and click 'view image' to get it enlarged):

[image: console output]

Instead, I would it expect to only push once when the app is started and then no more. How could the desired behaviour be achieved, or rather how can I trigger the push manually (e.g. via a scheduler, a click on the page etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

First off, you cannot trigger a request from the browser side using SSE. This is after all "server sent" events. The browser establishes a connection and then just waits for events to arrive if and when the server decides to send them. If you need to be able to trigger events from the browser, then you need WebSockets.

With that out of the way, here is what I think is happening with your code. pushData() sends only one response when called. After that, it exits and your server closes the connection to the browser. As per SSE protocol, the browser reestablishes the connection after 3 secs and your function runs again, exits and server closes the connection again. And the cycle continues forever.

To achieve what you want (and to benefit from using SSE in general), pushData() shouldn't exit. It should be a generator function and determine when/if it needs to send something to the browser. That way the connection to the browser will remain open.

Btw, you don't need _run_on_start()

Comment: Thanks for your input, I'll try that out soon and give an update.

Comment: @Dirk Did you try it out yet?

Comment: @ElHoussineTalab Nope, sorry, had other priorities meanwhile and never tried it out in the end.

Comment: Not to sound dumb, but on the Flask side, when you do the "sse.publish()" call, is that "closing the connection"? Is that how you're supposed to do it, or is there something I need to call after the publish to keep that open? I'm finding similar behavior, an interval param on a scheduler set to like 30 seconds, but seeing a publish every couple seconds.